# Facebook User with ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync (Unity)

Tags: parse-platform

I am using Unity Facebook SDK for facebook login in my project (C#) And I login successful with my facebook account Then I am trying to use logInSync through

```
ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync (FB.UserId, FB.AccessToken, DateTime.Now);
```

but in Parse cloud browser don't have any data about it :(

```
void OnLoggedIn()                                                                          
{                                                                                          
    FbDebug.Log ("Logged in. ID: " + FB.UserId);
    ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync (FB.UserId, FB.AccessToken, DateTime.Now);
}
```

Please help me, Thank you so much...!!!

Answer (score 0):

To find the root of problem you must handle errors that happen during LogInAsync task execution. You can handle errors this way:

```
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ParseUser> logInTask = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync (FB.UserId, FB.AccessToken, DateTime.Now);

    logInTask.ContinueWith (t => {
        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled) {
            Debug.Log ("Parse Login failed");
            Debug.Log ("t.Exception=" + t.Exception);
            foreach (Exception e in logInTask.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
                ParseException parseException = (ParseException)e;
                Debug.Log ("Error message " + parseException.Message);
                Debug.Log ("Error code: " + parseException.Code);
            }
        } else {
            ParseUser userFB = t.Result;
            Debug.Log ("Parse Login Succeeded with userFB.ObjectId = " + userFB.ObjectId + " userFB.Username=" + userFB.Username);
        }
    });
```